# Gulp-imagemin: how to preserve EXIF?

Tags: gulp-imagemin, imagemin

Is there a way to preserve metadata such as EXIF? I have been unable to find an option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different imagemin plugins have different settings.

#### jpegoptim:

```
gulp.task('compressjpegoptim', () => {
  gulp
  .src('./images/*.jpg')
  .pipe(imagemin([imageminJpegoptim({
    stripAll: false,
    stripExif: false,
  })]))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});
```

#### jpegtran

imagemin-jpegtran specifically ask jpegtran to remove the markers, with no options to keep them. If you modify [this](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran/blob/master/index.js#L17) line in the source from `'none'` to `'all'` it will keep the Exif markers. This can be seen in jpegtran's [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran) (search for Exif).

#### mozjpeg

This plugin seems to keep the Exif by default.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into modifying jpegtran.